# Saving an xml file without

Tags: c#, xml

How do I work with an xml file that when updating it, after saving the commented lines would still be present.

Here's my code snippet for saving the file:

```
    public static void WriteSettings(Settings settings, string path)
    {
         XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
         TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path);
         serializer.Serialize(writer, settings);
         writer.Close();            
    }
```

Comment: BTW you should use `using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path)) {serializer.Serialize(writer, settings);}`. Ensures writer gets cleaned up even if there's an exception.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand you requirement.  I would say don't use XmlSerializer because that's designed for creating serialized versions of objects in XML form.  Objects don't have XML comments in them, so the XML generated for the object won't generate any comments.  If you want to deal with pure XML, just use a simple XML parsing class, rather than one designed for serializing classes as XML documents:

```
string myXml =
   "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" + Environment.NewLine +
   "<!-- This is a comment -->" + Environment.NewLine +
   "<Root><Data>Test</Data></Root>";

System.Xml.XmlDocument xml = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xml.PreserveWhitespace = true;
xml.LoadXml(myXml);
var newElem = xml.CreateElement("Data");
newElem.InnerText = "Test 2";
xml.SelectSingleNode("/Root").AppendChild(newElem);
System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings xws = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
xws.Indent = true;
using (System.Xml.XmlWriter xw = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out, xws))
{
   xml.WriteTo(xw);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will overwrite xml file completely. In order to keep comments in existing file you have to read it first, then update and save.

Comment: How do I do it (reading, updating, saving)?  


Do you have a sample?

Is there no other way that I can save the comments? 

Thanks!

Comment: as well you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129414/how-to-insert-xml-comments-in-xml-serialization

Comment: (reading, updating, saving) is neccessary if you like to preserve comments done externally (like manual editing)