# Deserializing the comments in XML file

Tags: .net, xml, object, comments

I am trying to deserialize the following sample XML file.I have created the schema for this XML file.With the help of schema i am able to deserialize the XML into object.

But my problem is i have a XML comments(ex:`<!----Test-->`) on my XML file.Deserializer is not reading the comments from the XML to object which i created using schema.

And also i noted there is no entry available in schema for the comment node.

How can i read the comments from XML file to object?

Comment: please edit this so that your XML and XML comments show up (Use the backtick character to mark code blocks)

Comment: What exactly do you expect a comment to get deserialized into? A code comment?

Comment: Please specify the library you are using, e.g. .NET's System.Xml.Serialization package?

Answer (score 2):

The point of object serialization is to save the state of an object, and restore it later. Object fields are mapped to XML elements and attributes, and vice versa. XMLSerializer does not map anything to comments or vice versa, so you can't deserialize comments to anything in your object.

However if you use an XmlReader (as @Amigable said) which you pass to the [Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73.aspx)() method, you can then use that [XmlReader to separately traverse the tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28VS.95%29.aspx) looking for comments.

Unfortunately this makes it harder to connect the comments to the deserialized members, but maybe you could use deserialization node event handlers to help with that.

**Update:** a little elaboration on using an XmlReader with Deserialize:

You listed your code as:

```
XmlSerializer objSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomSchema));
StreamReader srmRdr = new StreamReader("Test.XML");
objForm = (CustomSchema)objSer.Deserialize(srmRdr);
```

I don't know anything about .NETCF or WM. (I didn't know anything about XmlSerializer either but I'm just looking at [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k674bf%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).) However here's what I was trying to describe above.

I thought you could use an XmlReader for Deserialize() and then re-use it, but apparently it's forward-only and therefore can't be reset to the beginning. So After your deserialization, re-open "Test.XML" with an XmlReader:

```
XmlReader xmlRdr = XmlReader.Create("Test.XML");
```

Then use the parsing [code shown here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28VS.95%29.aspx):

```
    // Parse the file
    while (xmlRdr.Read())
    {
        switch (xmlRdr.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                // You may need to capture the last element to provide a context
                // for any comments you come across... so copy xmlRdr.Name, etc.
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                // Do something with xmlRdr.value
```

Comment: ""XmlSerializer objSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomSchema));
StreamReader srmRdr = new StreamReader("Test.XML");
objForm = (CustomSchema)objSer.Deserialize(srmRdr);""

Above is my deserializer code.In the objForm object i am not getting the XML comments.What i am trying to do is i need to edit the existing XMll file to add new elements and and again need to serialise into the same XMl file.
But currently everthing is working fine but i am not able to retain the comments which existed in the original XML file.I am using .NETCF 2.0 in WM 6.5.How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

It does not say which programming language you are using, but based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129414/how-to-insert-xml-comments-in-xml-serialization), which is the exact opposite of what you are trying to do,
could you not insert an XmlReader like how an XmlWriter was inserted as accepted answer to that question?