# XmlSerialization - Add a comment

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I'm using **XmlSerializer to serialize and de-serialize** my xml files.

But is there a way to **add a comment**. I cant find it.

Something like this is what I have tried.

```
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    [XmlComment("This is the name property")]
    public String Name
    {
        get { return this._name; }
        set { this._name = value; }

    }
```

This is the code that serializes the Xml

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeObject));

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\path\to\file.xml"))
{
     serializer.Serialize(writer, scene);
}
```

There for hoping to get the output of

```
<SomeObject>
   <!-- This is the name property -->
   <Name>My Name is John</Name>
</SomeObject>
```

Ive looked everywhere. Its probably not available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert XML comments in XML Serialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129414/how-to-insert-xml-comments-in-xml-serialization)

Comment: I guess its similar but Im not using memory stream. I was hoping there would be an annotation like above

Comment: I know it can be done using an XElement or XDocument object, but that is not the same thing as the XmlSerializer.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

example here:

[How to write a comment to an XML file when using the XmlSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385921/how-to-write-a-comment-to-an-xml-file-when-using-the-xmlserializer)

Just implement IXmlSerializable in your class and in **WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)** check for the **XmlCommentAttribute** to include it in serialisation.